# Emacs Lisp nested function - void-variable error

Tags: elisp, emacs24

I want to make a timer, like this one:

```
(defun dumb (y)
  (defun P () (print y))
  (run-with-timer 0 5 'P))

(dumb 5)
```

Then Emacs gives me this error:

```
Error running timer `P': (void-variable y)
```

I guess the problem is that in the `(defun P () (print y))` line, the variable `y` is not evaluated, so when I run `(dumb 5)`, the function `P` tries to print `y`, which is undefined, instead of a literal `5`. But I don't know how to solve it. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

First, `defun` is for defining functions in the global scope. You only need to build an anonymous function instead, with a lambda form.

Second, `y` is only bound to a value while `dumb` is being executed (*dynamic extent*). Registering the function with `run-with-timer` is asynchronous and exits immediately. When your callback is called, `y` is not bound anymore.

You can activate [lexical binding](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LexicalBinding) in you current buffer with a file-local variable:

```
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
(defun dumb (y)
  (run-with-timer 0 5 (lambda () (print y))))
```

Alternatively, when `lexical-binding` is `nil`, you can "build" the lambda form with the currently bound value of `y` injected in it:

```
(defun dumb (y)
  (run-with-timer 0 5 `(lambda () (print ,y))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this is to pass the extra argument to `run-with-timer`:

```
(defun dumb (y)
  (run-with-timer 0 5 'print y))
```

`run-with-timer` accepts any number of arguments after the function to call, and those arguments will be passed along when the timer fires.